# SQL formatando campo

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
|VALOR|
|  1  |
|  23 |
|  5  |
|  41 |
```

Tenho a necessidade transformar:

```
| VALOR |
|  0001 |
|  0023 |
|  0005 |
|  0041 |
```

Existe alguma função que eu consiga fazer isso?

Comment: FORMAT(valor, '0000')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o campo for char:

```
Select REPLICATE('0', 4 - LEN('23')) + RTrim('23')
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função FORMAT.

```
SELECT FORMAT(valor, '000000') FROM tabela;
```

Referências:

- MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format
- SQL Server: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017